# Change design redirect page after send contact form in magento

Tags: javascript, forms, magento

how can i edit page which is displaying after successful send contact form in magento? I got these addresses: `domain.com/contacts/index/post`. I don't know how to edit it or only display statement on previous page in js `(domain.com/contact)`?

Answer (score 0):

By default you don't have such page. After submitting the contacts form you are redirected to the page you were before that (in most cases `/contacts`) with corresponding status message.

Comment: Look there https://antidotestreet.com/contact/ and send example message  u will be redirect into contacts/index/post - totally diferent page than /contact

Comment: I was redirected to /contacts/index/ which is equal to /contacts. May be you mean that the action attribute of the form points to /contacts/index/post but if you take a look at the code in this method you will see that after any part of the processing (no matter success or not) the user is redirected to (* / * / *) which is the default action in the default controller in the current module, in this case /contacts/index/index or just /contacts.

Comment: Oh... wait, this is some custom form, which is processed by the logic of the default magento contacts form. See the URL you sent me - /contact, and the default magento's contact form is in module /contactS. See that "S" in the end? :)

Comment: Yes i know it, but how to disable contactS/ page or redesign it?

Comment: The template file is: /app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/template/contacts/form.phtml. You can change it however you wish.

Comment: In this path i have template which i can find on `/contact (without S)`, but i don't know where i can edit  `/contacts/index/post`  this page...

Comment: Very strange. This should be the template for /contactS as the path says the same... To be absolutely sure which template you are using you can turn on the template path hints which you can find in System => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Debug (make sure you're in website scope on the dropdown at the upper left corner).

Answer (score 0):

go to app/code/core/mage/contacts/controller/indexcontroller.php go to post action you will find $this->_redirect() change it to as per your requirement to send after submission of form.

Comment: I try change it for `$this->_redirect('/contact')`, `$this->_redirect()`, `$this->_redirect('/*')` but nothing happens. Still the same situation. Default value is: `$this->_redirect('*/*/')`

Comment: use only $this->_redirect('contact'); using this you redirect to your-sit.com/contact

Comment: This is weird, i change it and nothing happens. Look at code: http://wklejto.pl/229533

Comment: code is come from this controller?please verify and var_dump() in it and check.i think other controller overwrite your existing controller.because it code work for me i have done this.

Comment: i found overwrite controller in this path: /app/code/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers, http://wklejto.pl/229549 but $this->_redirect('/contact') was existing before i found it - What i should have action in form? Where i put `<?php echo $this->getUrl('contact'); ?>` nothing happens when i click send button, but where is `<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>` message was sending, but i can't change this terrible page...

Comment: dont use $this->geyUrl(); at the and of your controller post action only add $this->_redirect('contact');

Comment: If i paste $this->_redirect('contact'); as action attibute for form i had error

Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::_redirect(Array
(
    [0] => contact
)
)

Comment: please refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32467/how-to-redirect-to-cms-page-after-login-using-an-ajax-login-register-module